# download a url in bulk and name with the url

Tags: download, url

Is there a way to load a list of urls...download the content into a folder and the name of each download is the name of the url?  I have about 1000 of these url's which are downloadable as pdfs.

http://www.swarovski-lighting.com/ws/web/coredatasheetstreamer.html?corepart=1239&region=1

Comment: Actually, there are a couple of ways to do this but they are not independent of what OS you have and what tools you are used to.

Comment: Are all of the URLs that you have from that website? i.e., they all have urls that do not end with a .file extension like .pdf ?Or do you have many urls from different sites? I have a powershell solution, but, it will not work on any URL that does not resolve to a file name or has a question mark in the url haha

Comment: they are all from the same site.  I have already created the urls...the only difference in each url is the code: 1239...should could be 2995 or 3601 or 5077 etc.

Comment: Ok, posting an answer shortly - are you on windows?

Answer (score 1):

Make a file called urllist.txt and paste all of your URLs into it. They should all start on a new line, example:

```
http://www.swarovski-lighting.com/ws/web/coredatasheetstreamer.html`?corepart=1239&region=1
https://www.dell.com/downloads/global/products/pedge/en/1750_specs.pdf
http://www.pizzahut.com/assets/w/nutrition/BrandStandardNutritionalInformationFINAL111314.pdf
```

**IF THERE IS A URL WITH A ? IN IT, ADD AN ACCENT GRAVE BEFORE IT**. Sample in the first URL above. Easiest way to do it, is to paste all URLs into notepad, then use find/replace. Find ?, replace with `?
Note the grave key is not the single quote key, but the key above the tab key with the tilde.

Open notepad and paste the following code:

```
Get-Content urllist.txt | ForEach-Object {Invoke-WebRequest $_ -OutFile $(Split-Path $_.replace('?', ' ').replace('&', ' ').replace('=', ' ') -Leaf)}
Read-Host -Prompt "Press Enter to exit"
```

Save this file as **downloadfiles.ps1**

Be sure to save this file in the same folder as urllist.txt

You can right click the file and run with powershell.